# Accidentally formatted root / partition, trying to Boot Repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a `Windows 8` and `Ubuntu 14.04` dual boot.
I would usually be prompted `GNU GRUB` console when turning on my computer, type `exit`and choose which OS I want to boot (in `UEFI mode`).

From Windows, I accidentally formatted the partition corresponding to the `root` `/` mount point (I had 5 partitions: `C`, `D` for my data and then `home`, `root` and `swap`) and can't boot to Ubuntu anymore.

I tried using boot repair following [those recommendations](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292641&p=13357102#post13357102) but it is stuck in a loop `Boot Repair` won't work:

```
File system repair requires to unmount partitions
```

I have already turned off fast start up on Windows.

Here is my boot info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12328218/

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you really formatted the `/` (root) partition, you have to reinstall ubuntu completely.

In case you have a system backup restore it and reinstall GRUB using Ubuntu install media.

Comment: Do I need to reinstall eventhough UEFI still prompts Ubuntu as a choice when choosing what to boot (nothing happens when I select Ubuntu but it is still listed..)? And is there a way to reinstall ubuntu while saving the /home and /swap partitions?

Comment: Yes - UEFI will be overwritten - boot from install media - open GParted - format all ext4 partitions - start installer - choose 'something else' and select the partition where you want to install ubuntu - that's it !

Comment: GRUB is stored partly on the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and partly on the Linux root (`/`) or `/boot` partition. Thus, when you wiped root (`/`), you probably wiped *part* of GRUB, but part of it remained intact on the ESP, hence your symptoms.